# CSS not imported into JS file in react + rails app on heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku

Hi I am having an issue of css on Heroku. The app is ruby on rails app with react on the frontend. The styles are not added. It works fine on local environment but not on production. I used the following link for adding react to rails
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-ruby-on-rails-project-with-a-react-frontend

You can see that css classes are not present in inspect in heroku app
[Inspect tools link Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJZgJ.png)

But the css classes are present on local environment
[Inspect tools link Heroku local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POx2o.png)

I had searched google for almost two hours but not found any relevant solution.

I have imported stylesheet to JS file as you can see in this image
[Import CSS to js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCbzu.png)

Comment: can you show your `application.html.erb`? Maybe you are not using `stylesheet_pack_tag` but `stylesheet_link_tag`? It could be the reason that it's not working after deploy

Comment: I am using stylesheet_pack_tag

<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application',media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
 <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
 <%= javascript_pack_tag 'index' %>